# Firebase phone number authentication failure

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm running app in debug mode and phone number auth is working absolutely fine and have uploaded SHA-1, SHA-256 even google app sigin. But when I upload it on playstore, it shows error "App is not authorized to use firebase autentication"

Please help[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your SHA-1 and SHA-256 to relase versions instead ones for debugging?
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth